# Laravel Storing data with Chunk

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need help on Chunk,
Below is the code where i send a request to the API endpoint,
Background: API Endpoint can only accept 500 signals, so from DB I am chunking data to 400 only and then converting results to comma-separated string.
Then sending that string to the API endpoint with the URL,

I am getting responses of all 400 results, but while storing in DB with that dataset, it stores only 1st result and then throws the error `Undefined property: stdClass::$data`

The problem is How can I store all 400 records with chunks? My foreach loop for store is running inside chunk function,

```
$commaSeparatedString = '';

ExchangeSymbol::where('segment', 'NSE_FO')
                        ->where('instrument_type', 'FUT')
                        ->chunk(400, function ($records) use (&$commaSeparatedString) {
                                $columnValues = $records->pluck('instrument_key')->toArray();
                                $commaSeparatedString .= implode(',', $columnValues) . '';

$url = 'https://api.upstox.com/v2/market-quote/quotes?instrument_key='.$commaSeparatedString;

$response = Http::withToken('eyJ0I')->get($url);
                    
$data = $response->object()->data;

$quote = new EodMarketQuote;

foreach($data as $d){
            $quote->open = $d->ohlc->open;
            $quote->high = $d->ohlc->high;
            $quote->low = $d->ohlc->low;
            $quote->close = $d->ohlc->close;
            $quote->save();
         }                                
   });
```

Comment: The error Undefined property: stdClass::$data suggests that for some of the chunks, the response from the API does not contain the data property. You should add error handling to manage cases where the API response is not as expected.

Comment: @N1Creator, if i ```dd($data)``` i get all correct response from API, it seems some issues in writing data to DB with foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing seems to be related to the way you're handling the database storing operation within your foreach loop, especially considering that you're using the $quote object outside of the loop's scope for each record. When you repeatedly assign values to the same $quote object properties and call $quote->save(), you're essentially updating the same record over and over again rather than creating new ones for each item in your dataset. Additionally, the error Undefined property: stdClass::$data indicates that in some cases, the expected data property might not be present in the response object, but you've mentioned that dd($data) shows correct responses, so we'll focus on the storing logic.

To address the issue with storing all 400 records from the chunks, you should instantiate a new EodMarketQuote object within the loop for each record. This way, a new database row will be created for each piece of data. Here's how you can adjust your code:

```
ExchangeSymbol::where('segment', 'NSE_FO')
->where('instrument_type', 'FUT')
->chunk(400, function ($records) {
    $columnValues = $records->pluck('instrument_key')->toArray();
    $commaSeparatedString = implode(',', $columnValues);

    $url = 'https://api.upstox.com/v2/market-quote/quotes?instrument_key='.$commaSeparatedString;

    $response = Http::withToken('eyJ0I')->get($url);

    $data = $response->object()->data ?? []; // Add null coalescing operator to handle missing data property

    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $quote = new EodMarketQuote; // Instantiate a new object for each record

        if(isset($d->ohlc)) { // Check if ohlc property exists
            $quote->open = $d->ohlc->open;
            $quote->high = $d->ohlc->high;
            $quote->low = $d->ohlc->low;
            $quote->close = $d->ohlc->close;
            $quote->save();
        }
    }
});
```

Key changes and suggestions:

1. **Instantiate `EodMarketQuote` Inside the Loop:** This ensures that a new database entry is created for each item in your dataset.
2. **Null Coalescing Operator (`?? []`):** This is added when attempting to access `$data` to handle cases where the `data` property might not exist in the response. This prevents the script from failing with an "Undefined property" error.
3. **Existence Check for `ohlc`:** Before attempting to access the `ohlc` property, check if it exists to avoid potential errors similar to the one you encountered with `$data`.

These adjustments should help in correctly storing each of the 400 records into the database without overwriting the same record or encountering errors due to undefined properties.

Comment: It almost worked, but let say DB have 600 data then will another 200 data will be processed in Chunk? I could see only 400 data was processed and stored in DB, how to take all data?

Comment: It worked, i moved ```$commaSeparatedString = '';``` to the scope of ```Chunk``` function and all iteration is finished.